# Set Track Artwork with AppleScript Using Existing Tracks

Tags: applescript, itunes, automator, itunesartwork

I am trying to make an Automater workflow that uses AppleScript. The workflow gets two tracks and passes them to the following script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
     set artwork of item 1 of input to artwork of item 2 of input
     return input
end run
```

I am trying to have the script take the artwork from one track and apply it to the other. However when run I get the following error:

> A descriptor type mismatch occurred.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the application. Try this :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if (count input) > 1 then
        set t2 to (item 2 of input)
        tell application "iTunes"
            if artworks of t2 is not {} then
                set data of artwork 1 of (item 1 of input) to (get raw data of artwork 1 of t2)
            end if
        end tell
    else
        display dialog "Select two tracks first..." buttons {"OK"} cancel button 1
    end if
    return input
end run
```

Comment: This is 100% correct and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. One question though, why do you have to set the data of item 1 to the 'raw data' of item 2? I would think it would be data to data. Regardless, thank you so much.

Comment: According to the iTunes AppleScript dictionary.
`data : data for this artwork, in the form of a picture.` 
**raw data : data for this artwork, in original format**.